# stackoverflow page not appearing inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I used to display web pages in `iframe`s. But when I tried to display my stackoverflow user info in an iframe, it went wrong. The content is not getting displayed. What may be the possible reason (or reasons) for this behavior? How can I display my page in an `iframe`? Is it possible to display it in `iframe` with pure `html` or is there any need for `javaScript` or `AJAX` or something like that? If this is not possible, is there any workaround for this?

**[Here](http://jsbin.com/ejinan/1/edit)** is a Live Demo.

Comment: If you look at the error console, you will see the following (in Chrome at least): "Refused to display '...url...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Comment: is there any workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Not on the front-end, no. What are you actually trying to achieve? There is a [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/) which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this could be same as that of Google. As some sites do not allow their sites to be iframed.

To quote from @Daan:
Google uses an X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP header to disallow putting their pages in iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Could be a case with SO too.

Comment: if thats the reason, is there any possibility for a workaround using Stack Exchange API ?